# How to 'tilt' an array

Tags: edit-mode

Firstly thanks heaps to everyone who helped me get this far with my first Blender project.
I have created a floating dock using Add > Mesh Cube for all the 'parts' to the dock.
Now I have imported an fbx file of a tire and created an array for 12 tires along the side (bumpers). The problem is that the tires on the left side are slightly higher (the top of the tire is adjacent to the top of the deck) yet the tires on the right side are slightly lower. I feel that it is connected with the tire array but don't know how to slightly 'tilt' the array.

[image]

Comment: seems like it would be the dock that is slightly skewed, since you're using a constant offset in one direction

Comment: or apply the rotation of the tire object? It's hard to say what is not aligned

Comment: Thanks. I think it must have been that I rotated the tire slightly as when imported I had to R(otate) the tyre 90 degrees and incorrectly selected the X and the the Y axis before realizing it was the Z axis and maybe didn't 'undo' the first two rotates correctly. Thanks

Comment: Hehe..personally, I've never seen a pontoon with perfectly aligned and identical fenders.. :D

Comment: Glad you figured it out, John.  If you want to you can post and accept your solution as an answer for anyone else that comes along.

Comment: Wow more things I am missing (accept a message as well as accept an answer) - are there any other 'things' I should be aware of when posting a question? I missed those upward facing arrows as they are greyed out and not easily seen on my monitor. Oh those perfectly aligned pontoons. I guess older ones certainly are not yet the new ones I watched being built on Youtube videos (where I got a lot of ideas including the newer PLASTIC floats secured beneath the pontoon) are as perfectly aligned as the skill of the builders Hehe.